# Is it possible to "bundle" template parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using-declaration

Is there a way to "bundle" template parameters together to avoid repetition?

I have several classes and functions that all use the same three template parameters.  It is not unusual to have a function that uses each class/function once.  The resulting code gets very messy very quickly.
Is there a more concise way to write this code?

```
// ContextFactory is a pointer to functions that instantiate objects that are subtypes of MetricContext
template<typename VertexID, typename EdgeMembershipType, typename SetBitmap>
using ContextFactory = MetricContext <VertexID, EdgeMembershipType, SetBitmap> *(*)(const char *);

template<typename VertexID, typename EdgeMembershipType, typename SetBitmap>
    static vector<ContextFactory<VertexID, EdgeMembershipType, SetBitmap>> buildCFList() {
      vector<ContextFactory<VertexID, EdgeMembershipType, SetBitmap>> answer;
      answer.push_back(MetricContext<VertexID, EdgeMembershipType, SetBitmap>::template make<NeoContext<VertexID, EdgeMembershipType, SetBitmap >>);
      return answer;
    };
```

Notice that almost half of this function is repetition of the string `<VertexID, EdgeMembershipType, SetBitmap>>`, but each use of this string applies to a different class or function, so I don't think alias will work.

(If it helps, the purpose of this function is to create an array of pointers to functions that will create objects that are subtypes of `MetricContext<VertexID, EdgeMembershipType, SetBitmap>>`

Comment: With C++11 you could bundle them into a template parameter pack. You lose some readability, though.

Comment: To begin with, you can use `auto` for return value.

Comment: FWIW:  When I replace the return type with `auto` (`static auto buildCFList()`), I get this error `'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension`

Comment: Do you need the alias 'ContextFactory' outside of the static function? If not, you can pull it inside and get rid of one line of template params.

Comment: The only place I need it outside the static function is in the return type.

Comment: Well, my solution only works nicely with C++14 and auto return type...

Comment: A rather cheap insight : use "class" inside of "typename" for template parameters, it is shorter and has the exact same behavior, by design.

Comment: Are you suggesting this primarily to reduce code length, or is there another benefit?

Comment: @AndyG Since there is always exactly three parameters, can I use a parameter pack? Or, do parameter packs only work when the number of parameters is arbitrary?

Comment: @Zack: You can use it in this scenario. It's probably overkill, but it'd save you some typing. `template<class... T>
    static vector<ContextFactory<T...>> buildCFList() {
      vector<ContextFactory<T...>> answer;
      answer.push_back(MetricContext<T...>::template make<NeoContext<T... >>);
      return answer;
    };`

Answer (score 5):

A rather more specific approach than @Quentin's is to make your template depend on a single parameter - which is expected to have typedefs for  `VertexID`, `EdgeMembershipType`, and `SetBitmap`.

```
// ContextFactory is a pointer to functions that instantiate objects that are 
// subtypes of MetricContext
template<typename Types>
using ContextFactory = MetricContext <Types> *(*)(const char *);

template<typename Types>
    static vector<ContextFactory<Types>> buildCFList() {
      vector<ContextFactory<Types>> answer;
      answer.push_back(MetricContext<Types>::template make<NeoContext<Types>>);
      return answer;
    };
```

Note that when you want to actually *use* one of the typedefs, you will need to use for example: `typename Types::VertexID`.

(Ideally you would come up with a better name than `Types` for the template argument.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. Let's define a little helper class to hold a list of types:

```
template <class... > struct pack { };
```

And a metafunction that instantiates a template with what's inside a `pack`:

```
template <template <class... > class T, class P>
struct unpack_;

template <template <class... > class T, class... P>
struct unpack_<T, pack<P...>> {
    using type = T<P...>;
};

template <template <class... > class T, class P>
using unpack = typename unpack_<T, P>::type;
```

And we can now store and use our parameter pack:

```
template <class A, class B, class C>
struct Foo { };

using Params = pack<int, float, double>;

unpack<Foo, Params> f; // f is a Foo<int, float, double>
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/488a185a90308a97)

Comment: The downside of this approach is that id does not help to reduce `buildCFList` implementation verbosity since inside the function, the fact that we use a pack is lost.

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen the more I look at it, the more I believe I've read the question completely wrong...

Answer (score 1):

if you're using C++11, you can make use of std::tuple to combine the variables into one.

A simpler example to understand the same can be

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
void fn() {

 typedef std::tuple<A,B,C> myTuple;

  myTuple tpl;
  cout<<sizeof(std::get<0>(tpl))<<endl;;
  cout<<sizeof(std::get<1>(tpl))<<endl;
  cout<<sizeof(std::get<2>(tpl))<<endl;

}

int main() {

 fn<int,char,long>();

 return 0;
}
```

For the problem specific to your question, you can create vectors of tuple as

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
void fn() {

    using mycomb = std::tuple<A,B,C>;

    vector<mycomb> v1;
    v1.push_back(make_tuple(10,'c',20.0));
}
```

In this way, you don't need to repeat the same. Tuple getter functions are bit awkward at first. The `cout` examples above demonstrates how to access tuple parameters

Hope this helps

Comment: Sadly, I find `tuple` to heavy-weight to use as a generic bundle.  It does too much, and makes things build too slow.